# Records not getting deleted in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using below query to delete the record of solr but its not getting deleted.

```
/solr-4.0.0-BETA/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<update <delete><id>1857494</id></delete></update>'
```

after this query i run

```
/solr-4.0.0-BETA/select?q=*:*&fq=id:(1857494)&
```

and i am still getting the results which means delete action is not performed

please suggest the solution

Comment: Did Sheldon Cooper really make this typo: `<update`? This may have caused solr to return a `400` bad input which you missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY

/update?stream.body=id:1857498&commit=true.

it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the typo you have for update not closing the `>`

You dont need the update just use the delete tag for removing the documents.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><id>05991</id></delete>'
```

Comment: <response>
`<lst name="responseHeader">`
`<int name="status">0</int>`
`<int name="QTime">8</int>`
`</lst>`
`</response>`

but its not getting deleted

Comment: add commit=true to commit the changes. Updated the answer

Comment: are you passing the correct id to be deleted ? and do you get the same result as query with the id ?